# Angular ng-repeat ignoring nested ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Howdie do,

I'm attempting to only display an option if the code that the client used to login, matches the $scope.code in the controller.

The HTML should then display the option that matches the code the client logged in with.

View:

```
<div class="">
<select id="customer-dd" ng-model="selectedCustomer" ng-repeat="(group, msg) in codes">
    <option value="">select...</option>
            <div ng-if=" 'group' == 'code' ">
                 <option value="{{ group }} ">{{ msg }}</option>
             </div>
</select>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.code = dataFactory.getCode();
$scope.codes = {

 'ABC': 'First option',
 'DEF': 'Second option'
}
```

There should only be one option showing as a client can't login with more than one code at a time

However, when I run this, I keep getting two input boxes instead of just the one that matches the code.

Is there something I'm missing here?

*** UPDATE ***

I've updated the code to the following and multiple options are still being printed:

```
<div class="">
<select id="customer-dd" ng-model="selectedCustomer" ng-repeat="(group, msg) in codes">
    <option value="">select...</option>
        <div ng-if=" group == code ">
            <option value="{{ group }} ">{{ msg }}</option>
        </div>
</select>
</div>
```

*** UPDATE ***
@ieaglle Removing the div allowed the if statement to excecute. The updated HTML is now:

```
<div class="">
<select id="customer-dd" ng-model="selectedCustomer" ng-repeat="(group, msg) in codes">
    <option value="">select...</option>
    <option ng-if=" group == code " value="{{ group }} ">{{ msg }}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

THANKKKK UUUU!!!

Comment: What version of angular?

Comment: you are doing it wrong , remove single quote from group

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however even when I remove the single quotes, I'm still getting every option printed instead of just the one

Comment: Also, I'm using Angular 1.3.18

Comment: Is it okay to wrap option in div? I've never seen that. Why not apply ng-if on option itself?

Comment: @Jimmy, please see this http://plnkr.co/edit/CzguhLmnbCabvBYnRwhc?p=preview

Comment: the logic here is all wrong.  You have marked the select box itself as the item to repeat, and for each select box, you are adding a single option.  You should probably be using `ng-options` instead, and not using `ng-repeat` or `ng-if` at all.

Comment: @ieaglle THANKKK UUU!!

Comment: @Claies, I will research ng-options as well

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ng-options` instead with a filtered object.

http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/hb7lu/

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="selectedCustomer" ng-options="msg for (group, msg) in filterObjsByProp(codes)"></select>
```

JS:

```
$scope.code = 'ABC';
$scope.codes = {

    'ABC': 'First option',
        'DEF': 'Second option'
};

$scope.filterObjsByProp = function (items) {
    var result = {};
    angular.forEach(items, function (value, key) {
        if (key === $scope.code) {
            result[key] = value;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Although this is overkill, since an object cannot have multiple properties with the same name, so you will only ever have 1 option in the select. As such, maybe a select is not the best option here, or maybe an array with key/value objects is better.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however even when I remove the single quotes, I'm still getting every option printed instead of just the one

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML to this.
Notice the change in the ng-if statement.

```
<div class="">
<select id="customer-dd" ng-model="selectedCustomer">
    <option value="{{ group }}" ng-repeat="(group, msg) in codes">select...
            <div ng-if=" group == code ">
                {{ msg }}
             </div>
    </option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however even when I remove the single quotes, I'm still getting every option printed instead of just the one

Comment: I made some edits. First I moved the loop to the option level and removed the nested option. Maybe this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Still, the same. It's printing both options instead of just the one that matches the code